# What command(s) can I use in a terminal to find a program that does a particular thing?

Tags: command-line, search, documentation

I often find myself alt-tabbing to google "How to do X in Linux".

Is there a way to search (say, man pages) in Linux to find tools that might be of use in a particular situation?

For example, earlier I needed the command to see how much space a folder was taking up. (Excuse my Windows terminology – I'm new to this!) Is there any way I could have found the `du -h` command without leaving the terminal?

Comment: Try `man apropos` -- `apropos space` brings up du, along with lots of other stuff.

Comment: I reworded your question a bit to avoid opinion-based ("best") answers, and towards specific commands.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3362/ .

Answer (score 2):

The `apropos` command (or `man -k`) will return all manuals that contains the specified search term in the `NAME` section (the first section in any manual on Unix). This section is stored in the "whatis"-database.

To find a command that handles "space" do

```
$ apropos space
```

On OS X, that will find `df` ("display free disk space") and other related things (but incidentally *not* `du`, at least not on OS X, it all depends on what's in that `NAME` section in the manual itself on your system).

```
$ apropos "disk usage"
```

Will bring up a tighter selection including `du` ("display disk usage statistics").

You will have to use trial-and-error for coming up with the search terms...  ;-)

The `whatis` utility does the opposite:

```
$ whatis du
du(1)                    - display disk usage statistics
```