# systemd, ctl commands

Tags: systemd

So I have been curious about one thing about systemd.

Lest say I wanted to update the time on my laptop. I use "timedatectl" command. But how did you know that the "prefix" for this command is "timedate"ctl? And not "timectl", or "datectl"?

I am guessing you can use systemctl command to list the units and targets in your Linux system? And I should find "timedatectl"?

So my point is where and how can I find the names of command when use ctl?

I hope I am making sense here.

Thanks a lot!
Denny

Comment: You look at what executables the appropriate packages contain.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3362/ .

Comment: Hi Ignacio, Can you please provide an example? Sorry, I am a Linux newbie.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `apropos` command to find commands if you aren't sure.

`apropos search-string`

Where `search-string` is along the lines of what you are looking for. Think of it as a way to `grep` for the commands.

Comment: sudo mandb was missing on my box

Answer (score 2):

To list manual pages whose title or description contains a word ending  with `ctl`:

```bsh
$ apropos 'ctl\b'
_sysctl (2)          - read/write system parameters
alsactl (1)          - advanced controls for ALSA soundcard driver
apachectl (8)        - Apache HTTP Server Control Interface
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of these two equivalent commands:

```
apropos your-command-pattern
```

Or

```
man -k your-command-pattern
```