# Significance of "ctl" in "systemctl"

Tags: systemd, terminology

Is "ctl" in `systemctl` an acronym for "control"? I couldn't find the meaning of `systemctl` on Wikipedia.

Comment: In the gist of "you should only ask practical […] questions based on actual problems that you face" (from our [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)) I'm asking: what practical difference does it make? what problem will the answer solve?

Comment: i can learn better, if i have a picture of the word in my head. so far i think about levers connected to a system: systemcontrol

Comment: If you're asking how to pronounce it, pronounce it however you want. I have seen both systemcontrol and system-see-tee-ell.

Comment: ok control is it ? then control. you can also write it as an answer and upvote the question.

Comment: It's trivial to deduce it means control: `man systemctl` tells: "systemctl - Control the systemd system and service manager". You can file a bug report so they dot the i's and cross the t's  in the manual.

Comment: This question didn't need to be asked.  even doing the bare minimum of research by running `man systemctl` would have told you what it is: `systemctl - Control the systemd system and service manager`

Comment: Even [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Core_components_and_libraries) describes `systemctl` as “a command to introspect and control the state of the systemd system and service manager”.

Comment: Related: [systemd, ctl commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/427328)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ man systemctl | head
NAME
       systemctl - Control the systemd system and service manager
```

"long name" is not a thing.

Read the man page before you bother with wikipedia.

Comment: thx. man page is a good hint